# nginx + PHP-FPM: Doing away with fastcgi params

Tags: php, nginx, docker, fpm

I'm doing a little experiment, a hypothesis if you will. The main idea is simple: three Docker containers, one is simply a data container with an index.php in it at `/app/web/` that simply outputs `phpinfo();` This works fine.

I have an nginx container that also is working fine, and a separate PHP-FPM container. Both are these are from the official images.

I had everything working fine with a standard setup, and even as a security measure bound the data container only to php-fpm, so nginx didn't even have access to the file itself. So the data container is mounted on the php-fpm container at `/app`, and all is well in the world.

All of this was fine. Then I started to play with some variables.

It occurred to me that actually, if nginx is just passing over the variables to php-fpm, then I could probably remove some of the params in nginx fastcgi setup, because why would it need them if it doesn't even know what's going on?

Things were going fine with `chroot` set to `/app`, and I added `chdir` to `/web`, but as soon as I removed `PATH_TRANSLATED` from nginx, it fails to work. I either get `File not found.` or `No input file specified.`

Here is the relevant parts of nginx container's nginx.conf, no `root` is specified in the nginx.conf:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY '';
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    break;
}
```

and the relevant parts of the `www.conf` pool:

```
chroot = /app

; Chdir to this directory at the start.
; Note: relative path can be used.
; Default Value: current directory or / when chroot

chdir = /web

php_admin_value[doc_root] = /app/web
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

So I tweaked and tweaked until I found the right combination. Here's my nginx config:

```
    location / {
      index   index.php;
      fastcgi_index  /index.php;
      fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
      fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        /index.php;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
      fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
      fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
      fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

      fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
      fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
      fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

      # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
      fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /index.php;
      fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY '';

      fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    }
```

And here's my pool config:

```
chroot = /app
chdir = /web
php_admin_value[doc_root] = web
```

I basically copied everything out of the default fastcgi_params file so I could see what was going on. The next step will be to test this with something in anger, such as the default Symfony 2 app.

Comment: Experimentation suggests that php-fpm runs the PHP file pointed to by SCRIPT_FILENAME; SCRIPT_NAME is ignored. Therefore, you could remove that line.